# Static code analysis tool for multiplatform project with good coverage of C++11 features

Tags: c++, code-analysis

I am an old school C++ developer and even today I have no professional [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) experience. I trust the C++ committee that the language is moving in the right direction, but it seems that in the projects I work the scepticism is dominant and a lot of the C++11 features are banned even before they are understood and explored.

Anyways, I am having a chance now to work on a new code base and I would like to apply all C++11 power, but I do not want to shoot myself in the foot.

In the past, I found some of the static code analysis tools to be extremely powerful teaching instrument to show me all these subtle aspects of the language.

For my project, I use clang, and portable libraries as [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) and [Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_%28C%2B%2B_libraries%29) that build on Windows, Linux, Mac and more.
I hoped [clang-tidy](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/), [clang-modernize](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-modernize.html), etc. will be good tools to let me tune my behavior to the C++11 feature, but they seem to provide very limited help - it literally took me like 2-3 days to adapt to all the suggestions they do... and I am sure that there are a lot of possibilities that I am missing based on *rvalue* references for example.

Some features that I would like it to have:

- When copy elision is not sufficient and forwarding interface will provide optimization.
- When some of the class members are not movable and auto-generated move constructor and move assignment operator is not possible.
- When local variable could be moved if this is the last reference in its scope.
- When `const auto&` is better over `auto`.

I have no price limits.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! It's quite unclear what you're asking for. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: @lzzy I am looking for: "static code analysis tool with good coverage of c++11 features"

Comment: That's a bit "too broad" I'm afraid. Have you checked with the link of my last comment? There are many details missing in your question, e.g. which OS it should run on, what your budget is. Possibly more, but when it comes to features I must pass, as that's not my area of expertise.

Comment: @lzzy - the question is on hold because is "unclear", but in your comment it is too broad - which it is. I feel if I give anything more specific - I will have to provide the answer myself.

Comment: @gsf Please clearly specify which OS it should run on. A "_tool for multiplatform project_" can be misinterpreted. Do you develop on Windows? I might have something to suggest once your questions is not in the "put on hold" status anymore.

Comment: @mguassa I use clang, and portable libraries as stl and boost that build on windows, linux, mac and more.

Comment: I really like your question and hope to see an answer. Could you please try to give us more info & we will vote to re-open. What about a list of features? And do you care which o/s?

Comment: @Mawg I do not know what exact features the tool should provide, I give 3 paragraphs explaining why. If I have to become an expert in the area to ask a question - what is the point of the website - something is completely wrong here.

Comment: Please, can anyone vote to reopen the question? I think it's clear enough for people to provide some answers.

Answer (score 2):

In the past, for old-school C/C++ code, I used [PC-lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/index.htm), a commercial software developed by Gimpel Software.

The company actually develops a couple of static analysis tools: [PC-lint and FlexeLint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/products.htm).
Pc-lint is for Windows systems, while FlexeLint runs on almost all systems that support C including VMS, OS-9, and pretty much all Unix systems.

> PC-lint and FlexeLint are powerful static analysis tools that will
>   check your C/C++ source code and find bugs, glitches, inconsistencies,
>   non-portable constructs, redundant code, and much more. It looks
>   across multiple modules, and so, enjoys a perspective your compiler
>   does not have.

Regarding the C++11 support, they have a dedicated page for it:
**[PC-lint / FlexeLint Support for C++ 11](http://www.gimpel.com/html/cpp11.htm)**

> Full support for C++11 and C++1y is our primary focus and while we
>   cannot provide a date for full support we anticipate a quicker release
>   cycle as we roll-out support for the remaining features.

So, at this time of writing, they don't support all the C++11 features, but most of them seem to be there. What I like is that the development status of the features is clearly and transparently reported on that page, along with a priority (for other tools, such information doesn't seem to be that clear or easily available).
For example, in your question you mentioned *rvalue*, which appears to be supported:

- Language feature: **Rvalue references**
- C++11 Proposal: **[N2118](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2118.html)**
- Available n PC-Lint/FlexeLint?: **Lint 9.00c**

Based on the information you can find on the website and on that page, the cost involved and your project, you can evaluate if it's a tool that can fit your needs. Others might know other tools, this is the one I suggest you to have a look at.

Finally, a list of other tools for C/C++ static code analysis can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2C_C.2B.2B). They do not all support C++11.

Comment: Thanks, this seem more like a "we do not have compile issues with these features", than "we have a good set of advices for these issues". Do you have personal observation in this aspect?

Comment: @gsf Honestly, I've never used any of the C++11 features, I only used that product in the past for old-school C/C++ code and I feel I can recommend it. As far as I know, for what I've seen lately and for the specific request you have, there doesn't seem to be much around. Having used the product before, and looking at the effort they seem to put on the C++11 support now, what I've suggested looks like one of the best options available. Note that I have no relationship with that company.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com), a pretty complete static analysis tool which integrates a wide range of features, and 100% integrated to Visual Studio.

Comment: It looks like that CppDepend uses clang-modernize, which is something that the OP already tried. See [CppDepend modernizer](http://cppdepend.com/modernizer).